# Python 3.8 xlwt invisible hyperlinks

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, xlwt

Hi i'm puting some links in an excel file with xlwt, but the links are invisible, i mean it will result in something like this :

**I cannot put the screen anymore after i edited the post... :/**

So the link is here, you can click it, but it writes nothing on the lines....I want the link URL to be written...

I did :

```
k=0
    print("Pour l'ICO "+"'"+cle+"' les profils LINKEDIN sont les suivants :\n")
    for x in range(0,len(val)):
        lien=linkedin_base_url+val[x]
        formula = 'HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(lien, lien)
        print(lien)
        ligne1 = feuil1.row(k+1) #On prend k+1 car en-tête en ligne 0
        ligne1.write(0,xlwt.Formula(formula))#Colonne 0
        k+=1
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work ! I tried to format Font too, nothing changed...If anyone can help =)

Stand alone simple example that will result the same:

```
#coding: utf8
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('test')

link="http://www.google.com"

formula = 'HYPERLINK("'+link+'"; "'+link+'")'

ws.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula(formula))

wb.save('test.xls')
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work because of my XLS reader....

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: yes i did, just my xls reader was bad....